# In Perl Windows, how do you replace everything after a word?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I'd like to replace a text from this

```
<!-- kv3 encoding:text:version{e21c7f3c-8a33-41c5-9977-a76d3a32aa0d} format:generic:version{aafc65d8-7a5a-4e01-bd8d-3ac118422503} -->
{
    _class = "CParticleSystemDefinition"
    m_bShouldHitboxesFallbackToRenderBounds = false
    m_nMaxParticles = 1
    m_nInitialParticles = 1
    m_flConstantRadius = 15.000000
    m_ConstantColor = 
    [
        255,
        0,
        0,
        255,
    ]
    m_nConstantSequenceNumber = 8
    m_nConstantSequenceNumber1 = 7
    m_Renderers = 
    [
        
        {
            _class = "C_OP_RenderSprites"
            m_nSequenceCombineMode = "SEQUENCE_COMBINE_MODE_USE_SEQUENCE_0"
            m_bMod2X = true
            m_bDisableZBuffering = true
            m_hTexture = resource:"materials/particle/particle_modulate_01.vtex"
            m_nOrientationType = 2
        },
    ]
}
```

To this.

```
<!-- kv3 encoding:text:version{e21c7f3c-8a33-41c5-9977-a76d3a32aa0d} format:generic:version{aafc65d8-7a5a-4e01-bd8d-3ac118422503} -->
{
    _class = "CParticleSystemDefinition"
}
```

This is the command I've been using:

> **perl -pi.bak -e "s/CParticleSystemDefinition"/CParticleSystemDefinition"\n}/g;"
> "C:\Folder\File.vpcf"**

and it has been producing this result for me

```
<!-- kv3 encoding:text:version{e21c7f3c-8a33-41c5-9977-a76d3a32aa0d} format:generic:version{aafc65d8-7a5a-4e01-bd8d-3ac118422503} -->
{
    _class = "CParticleSystemDefinition"
}
    m_bShouldHitboxesFallbackToRenderBounds = false
    m_nMaxParticles = 1
    m_nInitialParticles = 1
    m_flConstantRadius = 15.000000
    m_ConstantColor = 
    [
        255,
        0,
        0,
        255,
    ]
    m_nConstantSequenceNumber = 8
    m_nConstantSequenceNumber1 = 7
    m_Renderers = 
    [
        
        {
            _class = "C_OP_RenderSprites"
            m_nSequenceCombineMode = "SEQUENCE_COMBINE_MODE_USE_SEQUENCE_0"
            m_bMod2X = true
            m_bDisableZBuffering = true
            m_hTexture = resource:"materials/particle/particle_modulate_01.vtex"
            m_nOrientationType = 2
        },
    ]
}
```

So, how do I make it so that replacing something deletes everything that comes after it?
I'd also like to keep the command on a single line.

Comment: You're matching against a line at a time. Use `-0777`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I make it so that replacing something deletes everything that comes after it?

Need to match all that after it, as well, but leave it out in the replacement

```
perl -0777 -pi.bak -we"s/CParticleSystemDefinition\x22\K.*/\n}/s" file
```

Explanation

- With `-p` the program (between `""`) is applied to a line at a time. So to match multiple lines at once, as needed here, we need to read the whole file into a string, what `-0777` does; then our "line" to which the code is applied is the whole file.  See [Command switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches)
- Here we still need to enable `.` to match newlines as well, what it normally doesn't, with the `/s` modifier.  See [Modifiers in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers)
- Since `"` delimit the program text in Windows I use `\x22` (hex) for the `"` character in code. (In my tests on Linux escaping it with `\"` didn't work but it may work on Windows, what I can't test now.)
- The `\K` drops ("forgets") all matches previous to that point, so they are not consumed from the string; so we don't have to re-enter them in the replacement part. Thus only the following `.*` is replaced, with `\n}`, so removed apart from the needed newline and the closing delimiter.  See [\K in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK)

See the tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut)

---

A question came up of how to pass a list of files to this command-line program in Windows, like `*.vpcf` that one would do in Unix world (all files that end with `.vpcf`).

That is a question of Windows shell(s), and is not a simple matter with `cmd.exe` in Windows, but it is with PowerShell. So that's one way to go, to use PowerShell.

On the other hand, one can have a Perl program do that -- pass it a pattern to build the filenames from, like the extension, and have it build a filelist, read, edit and write back the files.  Then that program will be a bit more involved than the one-liner above but still rather basic.

Here is a shortcut, to still keep it as a short command-line program ("one-liner")

```
perl -wE'@ARGV = glob qq($ARGV[0]); $^I = qq(.bak); while (<>) { s/.../.../s; print }' *.vpcf
```

(same regex as above)

Comments

- The filelist is built using [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) from what is passed to the program when it is invoked (first argument in its `@ARGV` array), then that is assigned to `@ARGV` (for `<>` later)
- To emulate `-i.bak` one can use [$^I variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EI)
- The `while (<>)` takes a line from each file listed in `@ARGV`.  (Normally these are things from the command-line but now we explicitly assigned to `@ARGV`.)  See [<> operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators)
- I use `qq` operator for double quotes since `"` is a delimiter on Windows command-line

(I cannot test on Windows right now)

Comment: omg, what magic is this? ;D, thank you so much man, this has worked beautifully for me, and thank you for the detailed explanation as well, I believe I've just learned something new about perl thanks to you.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but how can I modify it at the end so that the replacement process applies to all files in the folder with the extension ".vpcf"? i've tried this and several other methods for hours and still can't get it to work, and i can't find anything about it online.

`perl -0777 -pi.bak -we"s/CParticleSystemDefinition\x22\K.*/\n}/s" ---> This here at the end doesn't work "C:\Folder\*.vpcf"`

Comment: @LGZana "_all files in the folder with the extension `.vpcf`_"  -- that is about the "shell" you use on Windows (where you type commands). With `cmd.exe` there seems to be no way to do file "globbing" like in unix (can't do `*.vpcf` or some such).  With PowerShell things look better; here is [one example](https://superuser.com/a/460651/426516) I see.  Or, you can use `dir` to get a list of files but then I don't know how to feed that to this perl command.  This would be a topic for another question -- how to get a list of files and pass it to a program, on Windows.  (Check existing Q/A first.)

Comment: @LGZana  Another option is to do this in the Perl program -- pass it, let's say, just the file extension and build the file list from it and do all the rest in it.  Then there will be a bit more to the program (still rather short, and can still be a "command-line" program, but more involved) but then all is done inside that program.  Much better yet, write a normal program (that is saved in a file).  Is there a reason that you don't want to/cannot do that?

Comment: @LGZana  I added a comment on this to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response! and srry i've only recently discovered perl and don't yet have the necessary knowledge to write a program. i've been experimenting with the second Command you provided, and this is what works for me on windows.

`perl -wE "@ARGV = glob qq($ARGV[0]); $^I = qq(.bak); while (<>) { s/CParticleSystemDefinition\x22\K.*/\n}/g; print }" *.vpcf`

This Command replaces every .vpcf file in the folder, but it has one minor flaw: it does not have the ability to delete everything after the word "CParticleSystemDefinition," so i always end up with my old problem.

Comment: @LGZana Hm.  Are you sure that it actually replaces files?  (Perhaps it doesn't match with that regex and doesn't do anything to the files so they really just stay the same?) Also, are there `.bak` files made?  Did I perhaps mistype something in that regex? (Is that long word correct?) Try to change it to something trivial, like `s/Particle\K.*//` (should leave nothing after the word `Particle`), just to see that it works overall.  I'll look more and I'll test more.

Comment: Yeah it works, and the bak files have been created. i've also changed the command to

`perl -0777 -wE "@ARGV = glob qq($ARGV[0]); $^I = qq(.bak); while (<>) { s/CParticleSystemDefinition\x22\K.*/\n}/s; print }" *.vpcf`

and it now replaces everything after "CParticleSystemDefinition". I'm not sure if it's correct, but it works for me. @zdim. thank you kindly!

Comment: @LGZana OK!  Shouldn't need that `-0777`, in this case `perl -wE"..." simply executes the Perl program in `"..."` (it doesn't read files at all). It's inside the program where we open and read files etc.  (Are you using the Windows "usual" `cmd.exe` shell ... or perhaps `PowerShell`?)  But, good if it's working!  Maybe it was just some silly hidden typo?

Comment: I'm using cmd.exe, and i'm not sure why, but i tried without the `-0777`, and it wasn't enough to remove everything after "CParticleSystemDefinition". in the absence of it, the command simply adds `}` to the next line rather than removing anything.

Comment: This command adds `}` to the next line rather than removing anything. `perl -wE "@ARGV = glob qq($ARGV[0]); $^I = qq(.bak); while (<>) { s/CParticleSystemDefinition\x22\K.*/\n}/g; print }" *.vpcf`. So i altered it by adding `-0777` and changing `/g;` to `/s;`. `perl -0777 -wE "@ARGV = glob qq($ARGV[0]); $^I = qq(.bak); while (<>) { s/CParticleSystemDefinition\x22\K.*/\n}/s; print }" *.vpcf`. And it now works flawlessly ;P

Comment: @LGZana  Ahhh! Yesss, it should be `/s`, yes !   That `/s` "modifier" means that `.` matches a newline as well (what it normally doesn't) -- that is needed so that `.*` matches all that text across multiple lines.  That's what I have in the first line in the answer (and am going to add it to the other one as well, just for clarity). Only now do I see `/g` in your comments above, sorry I didn't notice it right away.

Comment: @LGZana Also, it may (or may not) help to put `*.vpcf` under quotes, like `"*.vpcf"`.  Sorry I can't test on Windows now :(

Comment: `@zdim` No worries, I just tested `*.vpcf` with and without quotes, and they both worked, but thanks for pointing that out, I'll use it with quotes just to be safe.